# Getting 404 not found on adding NEW ROUTES

Tags: php, laravel

Everything was working fine before I installed a package https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php. 
Now I get 404 error on adding new Routes. 
*Old Routes are working fine, but new routes are not working*
**Web.php**

```
//old routes
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); //working
});
Route::get('email', 'EmailController@sendEmail'); /working

Route::get('/counter',function() {

    $counter = Redis::incr('counter'); //working
    return $counter;

});
//new routes
//Firebase admin SDK
Route::get("fire","FirebaseSdkController@fire");
Route::get("say-hello", function(){
        return "hello";
       });
```

**FirebaseSdkController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase;
use Kreait\Firebase\Messaging\CloudMessage;

class FirebaseSdkController extends Controller
{
    public function fire()
    {

        $firebase = (new Firebase\Factory())->create();
        $messaging = $firebase->getMessaging();


        $topic = 'News';

        $message = CloudMessage::withTarget('topic', $topic)
            ->withNotification("Hello") // optional
            // ->withData($data) // optional
        ;

        $message = CloudMessage::fromArray([
            'topic' => $topic,
            'notification' => [/* Notification data as array */], // optional
            'data' => [/* data array */], // optional
        ]);

        $messaging->send($message);
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far - 
`php artisan route:list`
*shows the new routes in the list*
`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`
`composer dump-autoload`

None of them solved the issue.
**Update**
Now, if I delete any route and do `php artisan route:clear`, I still can access the route. I don't know what's happening please help.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` & `php artisan route:cache`. run these commands

Comment: @danish-khan-It didn't work.

Comment: Please show us your entire `route:list` and the exact URL's you are seeing a `404` on.